# Order list of dependent calculations

Tags: algorithms

I'm working on an application where the user can add 'calculation' fields to a page. Every calculation field is dependent on x amount of 'number' fields and 'calculation' fields. If calculation field `A` has field `B` as one of it's components, field `B` cannot be dependent on field `A`, as that would introduce circular dependancy problems.

Example:

- Field A (numeric field, dynamic) **ID: 1**
- Field B (numeric field, dynamic) **ID: 2**
- Field C (numeric field, dynamic) **ID: 3**
- Field D (calculation: A + B / C) **ID: 4**
- Field E (calculation: A * D) **ID: 5**

Calculation fields are stored in the database as an array. A numeric value means a reference to another field (numeric or calculation), a string means an operator (+, -, /, * etc).

So field D would be stored as `[1, '+', 2, '/', 3]` and field E would be stored as `[1, '*', 4]`.

Given the fact that all fields are dynamic and can be in different orders, I need to figure out the order in which I need to calculate the fields. For example field D needs to be calculated before I can calculate field E.

What is the most efficient way to figure out in what order I need to calculate the fields?

**Note:** in this case the order is 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5, but that won't always be the case.

I'll be using PHP for the calculations, but of course this would be a generic algorithm which wouldn't be language specific.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: Thanks @Pseudonym, that's what I was looking for. Feel free to add this as an answer so i can accept it.